# How to remove values under a certain threshold but keep the coloring in a heat map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I made a heat map function based on `seaborn` that plots the heat map as I want it to be plotted. The only problem is that I also want to hide the values from the heat map in case they are less than 5 but I want to keep the coloring. I managed to to do it with this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mplc

np.random.seed(1234)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5) * 100, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
data_norm = data.div(data.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * 100

annot_data = data_norm.applymap(lambda x: x if x >= 5 else None)
# annot_data = data_norm.applymap(lambda x: x if x >= 5 else "")

def heatmaplotter(data: pd.DataFrame, vmin: int = 0, vmax: int = 100, **kwargs) -> None:
    if not isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        raise ValueError("data argument must be a pandas DataFrame")
    color = kwargs.get("color", ["w", "r"])
    cmap = mplc.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", color)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=kwargs.get("figsize", (16.56/2.54, 8.83/2.54)))
    ax = sns.heatmap(data, cmap=cmap, annot=kwargs.get("annot", True), linewidth=kwargs.get("linewidth", None), linecolor=kwargs.get("linecolor", None), fmt=kwargs.get("fmt", ".0f"), vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cbar_kws={"ticks": kwargs.get("ticks", [0, 25, 50, 75, 100])})
    ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", direction="in", top=True, bottom=True, left=True, right=True)
    plt.xticks(rotation=kwargs.get("xrotation", None), ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor", fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    plt.yticks(rotation=kwargs.get("yrotation", None), ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor", fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=kwargs.get("labelsize", 10), direction="in", length=6, width=1, color="k", pad=5)
    cbar.outline.set_edgecolor("k")
    cbar.outline.set_linewidth(1)
    cbar.set_label(kwargs.get("cb_label", None), fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(True)
        spine.set_edgecolor("k")
        spine.set_linewidth(1)
    ax.set_xlabel(kwargs.get("xlabel", None), fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    ax.set_ylabel(kwargs.get("ylabel", None), fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    savename = kwargs.get("savename", None)
    if savename is not None:
        fig.savefig(f"{savename}.{kwargs.get('format', 'svg')}", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=kwargs.get("dpi", None))

heatmaplotter(data_norm, annot=annot_data)
```

but the problem is that now `nan` is shown in the cells that are less than 5 (Figure 1).

[image: Figure 1.]
Figure 1: `nan` are present.

I want them to be empty. I tried with

```
annot_data = data_norm.applymap(lambda x: x if x >= 5 else "")
```

which alas gives `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`. I also tried

```
ax = sns.heatmap(data.mask(data <= 5), cmap=cmap, annot=kwargs.get("annot", True), linewidth=kwargs.get("linewidth", None), linecolor=kwargs.get("linecolor", None), fmt=kwargs.get("fmt", ".0f"), vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cbar_kws={"ticks": kwargs.get("ticks", [0, 25, 50, 75, 100])})
```

but that removes the colors as well which I want to keep (Figure 2).

[image: Figure 2]
Figure 2: No coloring in the cells that are less than 5.

Is there a way to mask the values that are less than 5 but still keep the coloring?

Comment: Re `ValueError: Unknown format code`: you can use `sns.heatmap(..., fmt='')` for strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add these code:

#### Part 1:

get data that you don't need annot

```
show_annot_array = np.array(data_norm > 5)
```

#### Part 2:

hide annot

```
for text, show_annot in zip(ax.texts, show_annot_array.ravel()):
    text.set_visible(show_annot)
```

### Final code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mplc

np.random.seed(1234)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5) * 100, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
data_norm = data.div(data.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * 100

################ Part 1 ################
show_annot_array = np.array(data_norm > 5)
########################################

annot_data = data_norm.applymap(lambda x: x if x >= 5 else None)
# annot_data = data_norm.applymap(lambda x: x if x >= 5 else "")

def heatmaplotter(data: pd.DataFrame, vmin: int = 0, vmax: int = 100, **kwargs) -> None:
    if not isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        raise ValueError("data argument must be a pandas DataFrame")
    color = kwargs.get("color", ["w", "r"])
    cmap = mplc.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", color)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=kwargs.get("figsize", (16.56/2.54, 8.83/2.54)))
    ax = sns.heatmap(data, cmap=cmap, annot=kwargs.get("annot", True), linewidth=kwargs.get("linewidth", None), linecolor=kwargs.get("linecolor", None), fmt=kwargs.get("fmt", ".0f"), vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cbar_kws={"ticks": kwargs.get("ticks", [0, 25, 50, 75, 100])})
    ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", direction="in", top=True, bottom=True, left=True, right=True)
    plt.xticks(rotation=kwargs.get("xrotation", None), ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor", fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    plt.yticks(rotation=kwargs.get("yrotation", None), ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor", fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=kwargs.get("labelsize", 10), direction="in", length=6, width=1, color="k", pad=5)
    cbar.outline.set_edgecolor("k")
    cbar.outline.set_linewidth(1)
    cbar.set_label(kwargs.get("cb_label", None), fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(True)
        spine.set_edgecolor("k")
        spine.set_linewidth(1)
    ax.set_xlabel(kwargs.get("xlabel", None), fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    ax.set_ylabel(kwargs.get("ylabel", None), fontsize=kwargs.get("fontsize", 10))
    savename = kwargs.get("savename", None)
    if savename is not None:
        fig.savefig(f"{savename}.{kwargs.get('format', 'svg')}", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=kwargs.get("dpi", None))
        
    ################ Part 2 ################
    for text, show_annot in zip(ax.texts, show_annot_array.ravel()):
        text.set_visible(show_annot)
    ########################################

heatmaplotter(data_norm, annot=annot_data)
```

[image: Final result]